# Decode Jwt Token using security Key System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 4.0.2

Tags: c#, jwt

Hi i am trying to decode a token with C# framework 4.6.1 using the nuget package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version 4.0.2.206221351 but i am not able to getting this working.

For version 5.4 this is the code i used:

```
   var token = "";
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Key");
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)tokenHandler.ReadToken(token);
            if (jwtToken == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;  // --> Error Here
            var tokenParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), // --> Error Here
                RequireSignedTokens = true
            };
            SecurityToken securityToken;
            var principle = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenParameters, out securityToken);
            if (principle == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principle.Identity;
```

Errors:

CS0103  The name 'IdentityModelEventSource' does not exist in the current context

CS0144  Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'SymmetricSecurityKey'

What could i be missing? is it a different way?

Comment: Do you have the following import `using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;` in your class?

Comment: Not available with out current nuget package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version 4.0.2.206221351. Should we install a different nuget package or just find the dll and add the reference?